# Enable and Disable Live('click')

Tags: jquery

I have a filter button.

```
$('#btnFilter').live('click', function () {
      // do something
});
```

I want to write a function that disable the option of `live` and another function that enable the option of `live`.

I read that I can do it by `die()` function. How can I enable it again?

```
function EnableLive() {

}
function DisableLive() {
    $("#btnFilter").die("click");
}
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: which is the jQuery version used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply declare a global boolean variable and toggle on that?

```
var clickDisabled = false;

$('#btnFilter').live('click', function () {
    if (clickDisabled === true)
        return; /* Stop further execution */

    // do something
});

function EnableLive() {
    clickDisabled = false;
}
function DisableLive() {
    clickDisabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing you will have to do is to separate the click handler like

```
function myclickhandler(){

}

$('#btnFilter').live('click', myclickhandler);
function EnableLive() {
    $('#btnFilter').live('click', myclickhandler);
}
function DisableLive() {
    $("#btnFilter").die("click");
}
```